# How to restrict a template function from being called if the type is not a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I only want the below function to be called when the template type is a pointer. The code below is a function of a linked list (custom class not anything standard)  that is a template of type t. A compilation error is being thrown when the template type is not a pointer, even when the function is not called at all. I need a way to throw an error only if the function is called from non-pointer template type and an error not to occur if it is called from a template type that is a pointer.

```
virtual void ClearAndDelete()
    {
        ListNode<t> * ptr = this->FirstNode;
        for (; ptr != nullptr; )
        {
            ListNode<t> * nextptr = ptr->Next;
            delete ptr->Item;//ERROR C2541
            delete ptr;
            ptr = nextptr;
        }

        this->TotalNodes = 0;
        this->FirstNode = nullptr;
        this->LastNode = nullptr;
    }
```

The specific error code from Visual Studio 2015 is 
Error   C2541   'delete': cannot delete objects that are not pointers. This is occurring on a template type that is 'unsigned short' even though none of my code for that template type calls this function. Suggestions would be appreciated.

As requested this is the definition of ListNode

```
template<typename t> struct ListNode
    {
    public:
        t Item;
        ListNode<t> * Next;
        ListNode(t what) : Item(what)
        {
            this->Next = nullptr;
        }
        ListNode(t what, ListNode<t> * nextnode) : Item(what)
        {
            this->Next = nextnode;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you show is the definition of ListNode

Comment: @MikeMB  I edited the original post to include it

Comment: If you find yourself having to do this, it sounds like your class is doing too much. Look up "separation of concerns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find out, where your class is erroneously used with a non-pointer template parameter type, you can use `static_assert`:

```
template<class t>
class List {
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<t>::value, "Template parameter must be of pointer type");

    //other stuff
};
```

If you want the `ClearAndDelete()` function to be usable with pointer and non-pointer types, you could e.g. use something like this:

```
template<class T>
void deleteIfPointer(const T& element) {}

template<class T>
void deleteIfPointer(T* ptr) {  
    delete ptr; 
}
```

usage:

```
deleteIfPointer(ptr->Item); //instead of delete ptr->Item
```

On a side note: Usually containers should not delete objects that their elements point to (If you need this behavior, you might want to use `std::unique_ptr` instead).

Comment: I agree with containers should not delete objects that their elements point to MOST of the time. In this case it more beneficial to implement this in this class for performance and code re-usability, I can explain why if you'd like. I do have two other solutions to this problem that do not require a function in this class but I would rather not use them for code re-usability and performance reasons. On a side note I will try template function specialization and add static_assert with is_pointer to catch if this function is ever called from a non-pointer type. Best answer so far, good job.

Comment: @DavidJones: Somehow I overlooked that you didn't want to use the class with a non-pointer type in the first place - sorry for that.

Comment: This works thank you!! I haven't debugged and checked it but using a function template in a template class compiles for this scenario,

Comment: Actually I do want to use this class with a non-pointer type, but I do not want this function being called when the template type is a  non-pointer type. For example if I use a unsigned short as the template type i want a compile time error ONLY if this function is called. Vice versa if I am using a pointer type as the template type it is ok to call this function. So... sorry on my part, it is a little hard to explain the question without typing a letter to someone and telling them exactly why and how you want the implementation.

Comment: @DavidJones: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is not possible if the function is supposed to be virtual, because if it is, the compiler always has to instantiate the function, even if it is never called. Otherwise you could make it a templated member function with a "faked" template parameter (a template parameter with a default value) which would only get instantiated when actually called.

Comment: @DavidJones:You might want to unaccept my answer that would make it more likely to get a answer that actually solves your problem.